# Network ping test has packetloss after some time

Tags: linux, windows, home-networking, ping, kde

Im currently running a Windows 10 instance on an SSD and I have a secondary drive. 
I created a second partition on the second drive (HDD) and installed Linux Debian with KDE Plasma on it. Since then i have ping drops i never had. Im pinging my router. I already changed my ethernet-cable and the routerport. I do not understand why it has so many timeouts. Im using a Asus P8H61 Mainboard and its integrated networkcard. I already tried to install new drivers or deinstall old ones and i removed my linux installation but no effect. Here is some output:

```
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=1ms TTL=64
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=3ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=1ms TTL=64
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=2ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=1ms TTL=64

Ping-Statistik für 192.168.0.1:
Pakete: Gesendet = 91, Empfangen = 88, Verloren = 3
(3% Verlust),
Ca. Zeitangaben in Millisek.:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 4ms, Mittelwert = 0ms
```

Comment: "_Eternity exists so that people like me may become able to learn the German language_", once memorably told us Mark Twain. The `ping` listing is looking quite all right to me, except those two "_Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung_" Lines. Or maybe you want it to be just perfect?

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai 3% loss is very high for pinging the local router over wired Ethernet. An Ethernet LAN's packet loss rate should be orders of magnitude lower than this.

Comment: @Spiff, I've just pinged my own router and it has revealed a 0% loss. It's better than 3% loss, but - let's face it - it's not "_orders of magnitude lower than this_".

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai 3% loss is 3 losses in 100 pings. One order of magnitude better would be 3 losses in 1,000 pings (0.3% loss). We can't calculate how much better your network is than OP's because we'd have to divide by zero since you haven't measured any loss yet. Your network might be many, many orders of magnitude more reliable than OP's. According to my calculations based on the IEEE 802-2001 BER standard for wired networks (8x10^-8 per octet of frame size without preamble), worst-case loss for a 64-byte ping request/response pair should be less than 1 in 100,000 (0.001%).

Comment: Yes, i know that 3 % of ICMP packet loss is not that much. But im directly connected to the router with an one meter long cable. And in i have strong lags  for just one second in game. Its much more worse than a normal 30 to 60 ping drop. Im just teleporting in the Online-Games.

Comment: So this I.E.E.E.-oriented Debate is actually for OnLine Games. Thank you, @Spiff, for the argumentation.

Answer (score 0):

So i think i found the Problem. I used my notebook and had the same issue. So it must have something todo with the router. Even when im pinging my DNS (a pihole) i get the same issue. That was the point when i thought it must have something to do with my own computer. But since my PC is connected directly to the router like the raspberry, i think it was just the issue on the router which doesnt forward my packets to the DNS. I dont know exactly the problem with my router. It just couldnt handle my ICMP Requests some times. So i reseted the router and now the problem is gone. Got 0% packet-loss now. My router is one provided by Vodafone. Just for other people looking up this thread.